# GeoTIFF to data.frame using R

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff

I have data with population counts in GeoTIFF format and would like to convert it to a data.frame using R.

The data I have can be accessed [here](https://jeodpp.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/GHSL/GHS_POP_GLOBE_R2022A/GHS_POP_E2020_GLOBE_R2022A_54009_1000/V1-0/GHS_POP_E2020_GLOBE_R2022A_54009_1000_V1_0.zip).

I would like to obtain a table with the form:

| longitude | latitude | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -180 | -90 | 0 |
| -180 | -89 | 0 |
| -180 | -88 | 0 |
| -180 | -87 | 0 |

So far I could obtain the values using `raster::getValues`, but the coordinate system is messed up.

Comment: By "Messed up" what do you mean? Some of the data from that link seems to be not in lat-long projection, so maybe you are seeing those projected coordinates. Can you please edit to say which file from the download repository (https://jeodpp.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/GHSL/GHS_POP_GLOBE_R2022A/) you are using.

Comment: @Spacedman edited link to the dataset and table with an example of how I intend to have the data.

Comment: I'm still not sure what "messed up" means. `getValues` doesn't show the coordinates at all, so do you mean you can't see the coordinates? Does `as.data.frame` work as in the answer given below? If not, comment on that answer with why.

Comment: Another problem with that specific raster is that it is 18000 by 36082 pixels, so any data frame would be 650 million rows and R would likely struggle to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
library (terra)

r = rast("your_raster.tif")
df = as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE) # na.rm = TRUE if you want to exclude the NA values from your df
```